# Import mongoose file in node app using ES6 syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning mongoose with Node.js. I have a connection string in mongoose.js file. I want it to connect to database when I run index.js.

**src/db/mongoose.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api');
```

**src/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import * from './db/mongoose.js';
```

I don't want to import anything from mongoose.js, just that it runs (which contains the connection statement) when I run index.js. I know I can achieve it using Common JS `require('./db/mongoose.js')` but I want to do it using ES6 imports.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a function connectDB. Inside the function create connection to mongodb.

**src/db/mongoose.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export default function connectDB()
{
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api');
}
```

import and call the function inside index.js

**src/index.js**

```
import connectDB from "./db/mongoose.js";

connectDB();
```